# Openlayers - How to import Placemarks from multiple KML-Files

Tags: arrays, openlayers, kml

I've got a lot of POIs in various KML-Files, which I need to import in my Openlayers' map.
The placemarks of each file should have his own displayable layer.

May anybody show me how to use an array to collect the unspecific number of KML-Files.

Here's my code, that imports a single KML-File:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Local Tiles", "tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 19, alpha: true, isBaseLayer: true}));

var kml = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "kml/test.kml",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: true, 
                extractAttributes: true,
                maxDepth: 2
            })
        })
    });


map.addLayer(kml);


var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( 7.21495 ,50.54819 )
      .transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), 
        map.getProjectionObject() 
      );
var zoom=17;
map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);  





var controls = {
  selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(kml, { onSelect: createPopup, onUnselect: destroyPopup })
};

function createPopup(feature) {
  feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("pop",
      feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
      null,
      '<div class="markerContent">'+feature.attributes.description+'</div>',
      null,
      true,
      function() { controls['selector'].unselectAll(); }
  );

  map.addPopup(feature.popup);
}

function destroyPopup(feature) {
  feature.popup.destroy();
  feature.popup = null;
}

map.addControl(controls['selector']);
controls['selector'].activate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example showing how to transform (or "[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)") an array of arbitrary URLs into an array of KML layers which can then be added to the OpenLayers Map in one go using the `addLayers` method:

```js
var kmlSources = ['kml/first.kml', 'kml/second.kml', 'kml/third.js'];

var kmlLayers = kmlSources.map(function(kmlLocation) {
  return new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('KML', {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
      url: 'kml/test.kml',
      // other options
    })
  });
});

map.addLayers(kmlLayers);
```